# ajax ignores url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/send.php',
    data: { 'username': user }
})
```

It ignores the url bit and sends the parameters from data to the current page and sends me to

```
mywebsite.com/currentpage.php?username=user
```

Instead of

```
mywebsite.com/send.php?username=user
```

Comment: "sends me to" as in the page redirects? Is this in the onclick of a link? If so, try returning false.

Comment: when the form is submitted by the click of the button. what do you mean return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that what you're experiencing may be a bug, as I am unable to reproduce it..  However, assuming it is jQuery, the correct option is `type`, not `method`, as shown in [the documentation of the `$.ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: '/send.php',
    data: { 'username': user }
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

.. As per the comments, it would appear you're trying to use ajax on a form.. without preventing the default action of the form, and unless I'm mistaken, when one does not supply a form method, it defaults to get.. and the action unless specified defaults to the current page.

In whatever function you are doing this in..  I'm going to assume `submit()` for this example, you either want to `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`, where `e` is the event object passed to the function in the submit event.  Example:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do your ajax here.
});
```

Comment: the string i get is username=234&password=&x=54&y=15 and i have no idea where &password=&x=54&y=15 is coming from

Comment: @user2088846 Firstly, show us the rest of your code, and more importantly, your html.  However, my edit should fix your problems..

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this recently. On investigation, I found that the original target of the ajax request was redirecting. Chrome Dev Tools was showing the second rather than the original target of $.ajax.